# org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException Error encountered in Linux environment but not in Windows

Tags: java, apache-poi, xmlbeans

I've been encountering a weird error when implementing an Excel (xls / xlsx) reader in Linux environment (Java 1.6) We are able to process **XLS** files but encounter a 
"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException" when reading **XLSX** files

these files are already added to linux classpath.

```
org.apache.commons.io.jar;
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar;
poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar;
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar;           
poi-3.9-20121203.jar;             
dom4j-1.6.1.jar;
```

p.s. other jar files are present within the classpath i can get the list but i'd rather not share it immediately unless its necessary.

This program also runs flawlessly in windows in both IDE compile and CMD compile.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that's the right classpath syntax? On linux, normally you'd use a `:` to separate classpath entries

Comment: its actually just a rough copy, we declared the class path like this:

CLASSPATH=.
mqsi/jars/javax.xml-1.3.4.jar
mqsi/jars/org.apache.commons.io.jar
mqsi/jars/poi-3.9-20121203.jar
mqsi/jars/poi-ooxml-3.9-20121203.jar
mqsi/jars/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9-20121203.jar
mqsi/jars/w3c-dom.jar
mqsi/jars/xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
mqsi/jars/dom4j-2.0.0-RC1.jar

and saved this in a file